# How to remove middle horizontal line in a table in Overleaf

Tags: latex, tabular, tabula, overleaf

I have a table in Overleaf. I want to remove the horizontal line (crossing the number 0.3). I know I can use \cline{} command to remove some horizontal lines, but I do not know how to use the combination of them.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Aspects} & Probability & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Methods} \\
\cline{3-6}
             & for DE Genes & Binomial Test & Tangram & stereoscope & BayesPrism\\
\cline{3-6}
AUC             & \multirow{2}{*}{0.3} & 0.519 & -0.261 & -0.020 & 0.996 \\
\cline{1-2}
\cline{3-6}
Best thresholds & &$0.398$ & $0.019$ & 0.204 & ${\rm e}^{-50}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The ROC Curve Summary for Data with 5 Clusters with Probability 0.05 for DE 
Genes}
\label{5 cluster 0.05}
\end{table}
```

The table looks like this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the line only in the first column, use `\cline{1-1}` instead of `\cline{1-2}` which will draw it over the first two columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Aspects} & Probability & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Methods} \\
\cline{3-6}
             & for DE Genes & Binomial Test & Tangram & stereoscope & BayesPrism\\
\cline{3-6}
AUC             & \multirow{2}{*}{0.3} & 0.519 & -0.261 & -0.020 & 0.996 \\
\cline{1-1}
\cline{3-6}
Best thresholds & &$0.398$ & $0.019$ & 0.204 & ${\rm e}^{-50}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```